# What's wrong with the logic on this program?

Tags: java

I have an issue with this fragment of code. It's part of a program that calculates what you would call nPr on some calculators. It compiles with no error but each time I run it and set n = 0 I get a seemingly endless list of error messages. Why can't it just print out "Error!" and terminate the program like I programmed it to?

```
{
    System.out.print("n = ");
    int n = j.nextInt();
    System.out.print("r = ");
    int r = j.nextInt();
    long n_fact = factorial(n);
    if ( ( (n - r) <= 0 ) || (n <= 0) || (r < 0) )
    {
        System.out.println("Error!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        long nr_fact = factorial(n - r);
        long nPr = n_fact / nr_fact;
        NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        System.out.println("nPr = " + f.format(nPr));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your code for `factorial`?

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code in a debugger to see why it never gets to your error checking?

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `factorial(n)` before checking whether `n > 0`. Move the line

```
long n_fact = factorial(n);
```

to inside the `else` block.

Comment: `factorial(0)` *should* be 1.

Comment: @A.R.S. - True, but the call is still in the wrong place. (What if `n == -1`?) If OP gets rid of the "endless list of error messages" then perhaps he can then ask about fixing the `factorial` function. `n == 0` is, after all, an edge case that might not be handled correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Move this line in `else` block:**

```
    long n_fact = factorial(n);
```

as it is getting triggered `even when n=0 or n < 0`, as you are checking `n > 0` after the above call, which you don't want. **I doubt if this(n <=0) is properly handled in your `factorial()` method.**

Alternatively put the check and handling on `n` in your `factorial(n)` method i.e. return 1, if n=0 and error out(throw excepion) if n < 0;